# How do you install Pop!_OS on a Raspberry Pi 4 with an encrypted disk?

Tags: encryption

The title says it all. The current version of [Pop!_OS](https://pop.system76.com/) for the Pi 4 does not offer the option to encrypt the root partition.

Answer (score 1):

What follows is basically [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1296450/1676566) adapted to the current Pop!_OS release, with additional tweaks. This took me almost a day of tinkering and testing until everything worked flawlessly with the fewest possible changes to the original image.

1. Download [Pop!_OS for the Raspberry Pi 4](https://pop.system76.com/). You should now have a file *pop-os_22.04_arm64_raspi_3.img.xz* or similar.
2. Take a fast USB stick or an SSD and connect it to a USB port of your Linux desktop PC (I'm going to assume a Gnome desktop). If partitions mounted automatically, unmount them (easiest via the **Disks** application) but make sure the drive still appears in Disks. Going forward the instructions will assume this is */dev/sda*.
3. Create a text file named *install* somewhere and open it in an editor.
4. Add the following script:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   # Adapt the following variables to suit
   image=~/Downloads/pop-os_22.04_arm64_raspi_3.img.xz
   drive=/dev/sda
   device=/dev/sda2
   partitionNumber=2


   sudo xzcat $image | sudo dd of=$drive status=progress
   sudo e2fsck -f $device
   # Resize the filesystem to minimal size to make room for LUKS header
   sudo resize2fs -p -M $device
   # Encrypt in place
   sudo cryptsetup-reencrypt --new --reduce-device-size 64M --type=luks2 --cipher xchacha12,aes-adiantum-plain64 --key-size 256 --hash sha512 --use-urandom $device
   # Resize partition to maximum. NOTE: growpart probably needs to be installed
   sudo growpart $drive $partitionNumber
   sudo cryptsetup luksOpen $device writable
   sudo e2fsck -f /dev/mapper/writable
   # Resize filesystem to fill the partition
   sudo resize2fs -p /dev/mapper/writable
   ```
5. Adapt the variables at the top to suit your situation. The `image` variable will almost certainly be different. The other variables are often correct for USB sticks and SSDs connected over USB.
6. Save and close the editor.
7. Open a Terminal in the folder where you created the *install* file.
8. `sudo chmod a+x install`
9. `./install`

   This will take a few minutes (even with a fast SSD). Along the way you will be prompted for your password and the encryption passphrase a few times.
10. When the script is finished, mount both the *system-boot* and *writable* partitions manually. On a system with a GUI, this is most conveniently done by powering down (e.g. in Disks), removing and replugging the device). You will need to enter the encryption passphrase.
11. Back in the terminal enter `sudo gedit` (or use your favorite editor instead). The `sudo` ensures that we can edit files in the *writable* partition.
12. In the *writable* partition open */etc/crypttab* and replace the example line with the following line:

    ```
    writable   /dev/sda2   none    luks
    ```

    **NOTE**: Apparently, the elements **must** be separated by TABS and there must be a LF at the end.
13. In the *writable* partition open */etc/fstab* and change the first line as follows (`noatime` only, the rest should be similar):

    ```
    LABEL=writable    /     ext4    defaults,noatime    0 0
    ```
14. In the *system-boot* partition open *cmdline.txt* and change it as follows (`usb-storage.quirks` and `cryptdevice` needs to be added; if present, `splash` must be removed):

    ```
    usb-storage.quirks=aaaa:bbbb:u dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=tty1 root=LABEL=writable rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline rootwait fixrtc cryptdevice=/dev/sda2:writable
    ```

    NOTE: The `usb-storage.quirks` entry is only necessary for some USB adapter-->SSD combinations. Without it, you will get [abysmal read/write performance](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=245931). If so, you should find the id of your SSD with `lsusb` and replace `aaaa:bbbb` with the id of your SSD.
15. Save all files and close the editor.
16. Unmount all partitions, power down the device (if necessary) and connect it to your Raspberry Pi 4. Initial boot will take a long time (>5 minutes). At times the boot process will appear to be stuck only to resume after a minute or two. It is expetced to finally fail and display an `(initramfs)` prompt.
17. At the `(initramfs)` prompt, enter `cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda2 writable`.
18. At the `(initramfs)` prompt, enter `exit`. The boot process will now resume and boot into Pop!_OS.
19. After going through initial setup, open a Terminal and enter `sudo update-initramfs -u`.
20. `sudo reboot`. After a few seconds, the system should ask you for the encryption passphrase and then quickly boot to the login screen.